# Web application freezes with signalR multiple requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, signalr, service-broker

I have an application in ASP.NET MVC where i want to see real time updates from a SQL server database using Service Broker and SQL Dependency.
The issue comes when multiple users are accessing the application. The browser RAM usage increases in client side, and the browser freezes.
After a while it becomes responsive again. I use SQL Server 2014, IIS 7 and tested on Internet Explorer and Mozilla.

Hope I given all the details.

I enabled Service Broker like this: `ALTER DATABASE testDB SET ENABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE ;`

In Startup.cs I added `app.MapSignalR();`
In Global.asax I have:

```
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            //Start SqlDependency with application initialization
            SqlDependency.Start(connString);
        }

        protected void Application_End()
        {
            //Stop SQL dependency
            SqlDependency.Stop(connString);
        }
```

Below is the code:

**HUB:**

```
 public class MessagesHub : Hub
    {
        private static string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString();
        public void Hello()
        {
            Clients.All.hello();
        }

        [HubMethodName("sendMessages")]
        public static void SendMessages()
        {
            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MessagesHub>();
            context.Clients.All.updateMessages();
        }       
    }
```

**VIEW:**

```
$(function () {
    var notifications = $.connection.messagesHub;
    notifications.client.updateMessages = function () {
        getAllMessages()

    };
    // Start the connection.
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        alert("connection started")
        getAllMessages();
    }).fail(function (e) {
        alert(e);
    });
});

function getAllMessages()
{
    var tbl = $('#messagesTable');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/home/GetMessages',
        contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        async: true
    }).success(function (result) {

        tbl.empty().append(result);
    }).error(function () {

    });
}
```

**Get data from database:**

```
                using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT Id, Importance,Subject, EnterTime, TicketStatus, Resolution, AssignedTo, UserName, ReAssignedTo FROM dbo.TicketInfo", connection))
                {
                    command.Notification = null;

                    var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection.Open();

                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        result.Add(item: new TicketInfoModel
                        {
                             Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]),
                             Importance = reader[1].ToString(),
                             Subject = reader[2].ToString(),
                             EnterTime = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[3]),
                             TicketStatus = reader[4].ToString(),
                             Resolution = reader[5].ToString(),
                             AssignedTo = reader[6].ToString(),
                             UserName = reader[7].ToString(),
                             ReAssignedTo = reader[8].ToString()
                        });
                   }
                    reader.Close();
                    command.Dispose();
                }

        private void dependency_OnChange(object sender,SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
            {
                MessagesHub.SendMessages();
            }
        }
```

Comment: My SignalR understanding is rather poor, but *I think* what happens is that every client subscribes to notification changes, and then every update triggers notification to each subscription, and SignalR then updates *all* clients. So if you have N clients connected and a single update occurs, each client gets notified N times, instead of each client being notified once. This is because you have N pending query notifications.

Comment: You can try something like https://github.com/rusanu/linqtocache which creates only one notification for all N clients (1st sets up the notification, subsequent calls get the data from cache)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll give it a try. Is there a method i can use without using EntityFramework ?